# Using ref insted of fixed pointers for P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, unmanaged

I'm trying to write a wrapper for an unmanaged library written in C++. The coder of the library gave me an example C# wrapper which includes `DllImport`s like this:

```
[DllImport(LibraryPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int doSomething(int inputArraySize, byte* inputArrayPointer, out int outputInteger, out int outputArraySize, out float* outputArrayPointer);

public static int DoSomething(byte[] inputArray, out int outputInteger, out float[] outputArray)
{
    int arraySize = inputArray.Length;

    int outputArraySize;
    float* outputArrayPointer;
    outputArray = null;

    fixed (byte* arrayPointer = inputArray)
    {
        int result = doSomething(arraySize, arrayPointer, out outputInteger, out outputArraySize, out outputArrayPointer);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            outputArray = new float[outputArraySize];

            for (int i = 0; i < outputArraySize; i++)
            {
                outputArray[i] = outputArrayPointer[i];
            }

            // This is another imported function.
            freePointer(outputArrayPointer);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

He's using `fixed` in the code, and I'm wondering if we could just use `ref` and just lose all the unsafe code, and pointers. I can rewrite it as:

```
[DllImport(LibraryPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int doSomething(int arraySize, ref byte[] arrayPointer, out int someInteger, out int outputArraySize, out float[] someArrayPointer);

public static int DoSomething(byte[] inputArray, out int outputInteger, out float[] outputArray)
{
    int outputArraySize;

    int result = doSomething(inputArray.Length, ref inputArray, out outputInteger, out outputArraySize, out outputArray);

    return result;
}
```

Is the above code equivalent in meaning to the first one with pointers?

1. Is it ok to use my version?
2. Are there any downside to using my version?
3. When I use `ref`, will the array passed to the unmanaged libraray function be safe throughout the function run?
4. And what do you think the `freePointer()` function does? The pointer is going to be collected by the garbage collection anyways. Why do we need such a function?

I'd appreciate any suggestions on this matter.

**Edit:** I think I can't just get a C++ pointer as a C# array without some extra code. What is the best way? Is there a way to do all these stuff without using unsafe code and pointers?

**Edit 2:** I think the `freePointer()` function frees the arrays allocated by unmanaged code. But how can it free the array with just the pointer to it, without taking the array size as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code (with some small modifications) will work for passing pointers to an array *from* managed code *to* native code. It won't work in the opposite direction, because native code doesn't know how to allocate a managed array (`float[]`) so you can't expect to treat it as one on the managed side.

But instead of passing a raw `float *` back, you can type it as returning an `IntPtr`, and use [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a53bd6cz.aspx) to extract the data.

Putting this together, the new P/Invoke signature and code will look like:

```
[DllImport(...)]
internal static extern int doSomething(int arraySize, byte[] arrayPointer,
    out int outputInteger, out int outputArraySize,
    out IntPtr outputArrayPointer);

[DllImport(...)]
internal static extern void freePointer(IntPtr pointer);

public static int DoSomething(byte[] inputArray, out int outputInteger, out float[] outputArray)
{
    outputArray = null;
    int outputArraySize;
    IntPtr outputArrayPointer;

    int result = doSomething(inputArray.Length, inputArray, out outputInteger, out outputArraySize, out outputArrayPointer);

    if (result == 0)
    {
        outputArray = new float[outputArraySize];
        Marshal.Copy(outputArrayPointer, outputArray, 0, outputArraySize);

        freePointer(outputArrayPointer);
    }

    return result;
}
```

When a P/Invoke signature is written as taking an array, the marshalling layer automatically pins the array in memory (so it can't be freed or moved, making it safe to pass it to native code), then passes a pointer to the first element in the array to the native code. By contrast, `ref inputArray` passes a pointer to the managed array object (which is a different location in memory).

These changes will let you eliminate the `fixed (byte* arrayPointer` from your calling code, and you can use an `IntPtr` for the native code to pass the data back to you. Because the native code allocated the memory, the .NET Garbage Collector doesn't know how to free it, so calling `freePointer` after you've copied the data is very important. It will know how much data to free because the allocation routine that allocated the memory will have stored the size of the allocated block somewhere (often in a header block before the allocated memory); this means you don't need to pass the array size to `freePointer`.

Comment: Can I use `IntPtr` rather than `float*`?

Comment: @hattenn: Yes you can--great suggestion! I've improved the code to show how to use `IntPtr`.